# User variable in MySQL subquery

Tags: mysql, database

```
Query Output:
> 

SELECT
  @foo := 1,
  @foo,
  (SELECT @foo),
  (SELECT foo FROM (SELECT @foo AS foo) subselect)

+ -------------- + --------- + ------------------ + ----------------------------------------------------- +
| @foo := 1      | @foo      | (SELECT @foo)      | (SELECT foo FROM (SELECT @foo AS foo) subselect)      |
+ -------------- + --------- + ------------------ + ----------------------------------------------------- +
| 1              | 1         | 1                  | 0                                                     |
+ -------------- + --------- + ------------------ + ----------------------------------------------------- +
1 rows
```

Well... I just want to know why fourth column value is 0 instead 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this `FROM (SELECT @foo AS foo)` is evaluated before this `@foo := 1`. Basically anything in FROM will be evaluated before your SELECT.

It actually should be null but Im guessing you've assigned your session variable a value of zero somewhere else.

Comment: Ben, you are right. Zero is the original value of my session variable. Anyway, is there no way to retrieve the value (1)?

Comment: At the time you are retrieving it, it has not yet been assigned a value of 1. You can assign the value in the FROM clause and it will be assigned first.

`SELECT 
@foo, 
(SELECT subselect.foo FROM (SELECT @foo := 1) AS init, (SELECT @foo AS foo) subselect)`

Comment: `FROM (SELECT @foo AS foo) subselect` will always take place prior to your select assignment ` SELECT @foo := 1`. 
You could do `SELECT (SELECT @foo FROM (SELECT @foo := 1) a), (SELECT foo FROM (SELECT @foo AS foo) subselect)` The earlier FROM clause will assign the value to @foo prior to your subselect.