# User variable not updating in subquery

Tags: mysql, mariadb, recursive-datastructures

I am using a RECURSIVE statement on MariaDB, to get a product category path when I know the product category unique ID, from a self-referencing category table.

This works:

```
WITH RECURSIVE categories AS (
        SELECT * FROM tbl_eav_categories tec2 WHERE tec2.category_id = 1023
        UNION
        SELECT tec3.* FROM tbl_eav_categories tec3, categories AS c WHERE tec3.category_id = c.parent_category_id
        )
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(category_default_label,' [',category_id,']') ORDER BY category_id ASC SEPARATOR ' >> ') FROM categories
```

And returns:

```
Consumables [7] >> Catering Equipment and Supplies [95] >> Tea Bags [1023]
```

Great.

But now I need to list all category ID's and in the second column, their paths.
I thought this would simply be a matter of doing a SELECT on the primary category table ('tbl_eav_categories') table, and dropping the above query in as a subquery column. Like this:

```
SELECT
    @CatID := category_id AS 'cat_id',
    (
    WITH RECURSIVE categories AS (
        SELECT * FROM tbl_eav_categories tec2 WHERE tec2.category_id = @CatID
        UNION
        SELECT tec3.* FROM tbl_eav_categories tec3, categories AS c WHERE tec3.category_id = c.parent_category_id
        )
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(category_default_label,' [',category_id,']') ORDER BY category_id ASC SEPARATOR ' >> ') FROM categories
    ) 'categorypath'
FROM tbl_eav_categories;
```

However, all I get is:

```
cat_id  categorypath
1   Bearings [1]
2   Bearings [1]
3   Bearings [1]
4   Bearings [1]
5   Bearings [1]
6   Bearings [1]
...
```

(like this until the bottom of the entire result set).

After some research, I do believe it has something to do with the @CatID variable being evaluated before it gets assigned, but I can't work out how to work around it.

I tried to follow Ben English's guidance here: [User variable in MySQL subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536575/user-variable-in-mysql-subquery) but it baffles me :(

Please help! :)

Comment: I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with example data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found the answer, by including the entire table scan in the actual CTE:

```
WITH RECURSIVE category_path (id, title, path) AS
(
  SELECT category_id, category_default_label, category_default_label path FROM tbl_eav_categories WHERE parent_category_id IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.category_id, c.category_default_label, CONCAT(cp.path, ' [',c.parent_category_id, '] >> ', c.category_default_label) FROM category_path cp JOIN tbl_eav_categories c ON cp.id = c.parent_category_id
)
SELECT id,path FROM category_path
ORDER BY path;
```